# Sql Server: cte query with outer table

Tags: sql-server-2012

i have this code:

```
with cte as
(select m.ID , 1 i from MyTable m union all
 select ID  , cte.i +1 i from cte  where i < 5)
select * from cte
```

error message: 
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

What is wrong?

Comment: `with` must begin the statement.  Try adding a `;` before the line, like `; with cte as ...`

Comment: Genius It works, I have no idea what that means ";" Can you give me a link to an explanation on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @MyTable table (id int)
insert @MyTable values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

with cte(id,i) as
(select m.ID , 1 from @MyTable m union all
 select ID  , cte.i +1  from cte  where cte.i < 5)
select * from cte
```

Comment: watch for ";" in second line